# View Controls show/hide WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have a View (in MVVM) which have some controls including a treeview. A ViewModel which is the datacontext and a Model, everything is working fine till now. **I have two cases:
**

1. I want my View to show a ContextMenu against Treeview items.
2. The other case, it should not show a ContextMenu against the Treeview items

Is this possible with one View or there should be two different Views for this purpose, for my personal work it would be better if I have one View.

The VM and model are very simple just having the binded properties of the View.

**View.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SPM.SystemExplorer.View.SystemExplorerView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SPM.SystemExplorer.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:SPM.SystemExplorer.ViewModel"
         xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:SPM.SystemExplorer.Classes">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:SystemExplorerViewVM></viewModel:SystemExplorerViewVM>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Test}"></Label>
        <TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SystemProjects}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type classes:SystemProject}" ItemsSource="{Binding ParticipantProjects}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding NameOfSystemProject}"></TreeViewItem>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding AuthorOfSystemProject}"></TreeViewItem>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type classes:ParticipantProject}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding NameOfParticipantProject}"></TreeViewItem>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding AuthorOfParticipantProject}"></TreeViewItem>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You could set a property of SystemExplorerViewVM to 'A' or 'B' and use a data trigger.

Comment: Could you please give an example by writing few lines of it, I am a beginner in WPF.

Comment: I think I didnt explain it right, 
What I wanted to say is:

Actually I have two cases for my view. First, I want to see my view having a contextmenu over a treeview item if I right click on it. Second case, I have the same view but no context menu over a treeview item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a property (`ShowContextMenu`) to your `SystemExplorerViewVM` class that you set to `true`/`false` depending on whether you want to display the `ContextMenu`. You could then use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` in your XAML:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SystemProjects}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
            <MenuItem Header="1" />
            <MenuItem Header="2" />
        </ContextMenu>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.ShowContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type classes:SystemProject}" ItemsSource="{Binding ParticipantProjects}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding NameOfSystemProject}"></TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding AuthorOfSystemProject}"></TreeViewItem>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type classes:ParticipantProject}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding NameOfParticipantProject}"></TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding AuthorOfParticipantProject}"></TreeViewItem>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: I am getting some binding errors in the datatrigger binding, I am trying to fix it.

Comment: I am having this error and stuck at this point.

BindingExpression path error: 'ShowContextMenu' property not found on 'object' ''TreeViewItem' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=ShowContextMenu; DataItem='TreeViewItem' (Name=''); target element is 'TreeViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

Comment: Sorry, it should be Binding DataContext.ShowContextMenu ... Also make sure that you add the property to the SystemExplorerViewVM class.

Comment: The "ShowContextMenu" is accessible by binding but "DataContext.ShowContextMenu" is not accessible in xaml

Comment: "accessible in xaml"? What does that mean? Try to run the code.

Comment: oh ok! I build it again, previous build errors. Thanks for the great help!!!, I will the accept the answer